# Swiping Images with Page Control in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, uipagecontrol

I am trying to make practice app where i can scroll images with page control. I am able to scroll images and able to include the page control. But the problem i face is i am not able to interlink the two. Meaning to say when I scroll the images, the page control is not affected and when i change the page control, the scrolling of the images is unaffected.

I have referred to this: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/ for the scrolling with page control.

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UIPageControl *pageControl;

    BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView,pageControl;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpeg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpeg" ], nil];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * images.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imgView.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        imgView.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.scrollView = nil;
    self.pageControl = nil;
}

- (IBAction)changePage{
        // update the scroll view to the appropriate page
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * self.pageControl.currentPage;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
}

@end
```

Need some guidance on this... Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether you have set the delegate of the scroll view to the ViewController

And you have just set the pageControlBeingUsed to YES or NO and you have not used it anywhere in the ViewController

Comment: where to use it? can give me a idea of where to use it?

Comment: changed the code now... included the pageControlBeingUsed in the scrollViewDidScroll function.. still no difference...

Comment: Is it possible to create circular swipe?.... how to do circular swipe by using above code....Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Singapore did u mean moving your finger following a circular path to achieve the above said

Answer (score 4):

I learned page control and scrollView from this tutorial, its very clearly written, hope it helps you http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Comment: i created the new practice app following the tutorial and it doesn't work still...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063303/swiping-images-with-page-control-in-iphone-part-2